# Core Data: Fetch all entities in a to-many-relationship of a particular object?

Tags: iphone, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

in my iPhone application I am using simple Core Data Model with two entities (**Item** and **Property**):

**Item**
name
*properties*

**Property**
name
value
*item*

**Item** has one attribute (name) and one one-to-many-relationship (*properties*). Its inverse relationship is *item*. **Property** has two attributes the according inverse relationship.

Now I want to show my data in table views on two levels. The first one lists all items; when one row is selected, a new UITableViewController is pushed onto my UINavigationController's stack. The new UITableView is supposed to show all properties (i.e. their names) of the selected item.

To achieve this, I use a `NSFetchedResultsController` stored in an instance variable. On the first level, everything works fine when setting up the NSFetchedResultsController like this:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

    // goal: tell the FRC to fetch all item objects.
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.moContext];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetch setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetch setFetchBatchSize:10];

    NSFetchedResultsController *frController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetch managedObjectContext:self.moContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"cache"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = frController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [sort release];
    [frController release];
    [fetch release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

However, on the second-level UITableView, I seem to do something wrong. I implemented the fetchedresultsController in a similar way:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

    // goal: tell the FRC to fetch all property objects that belong to the previously selected item
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // fetch all Property entities.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Property" inManagedObjectContext:self.moContext];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];

    // limit to those entities that belong to the particular item
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item.name like '%@'",self.item.name]];
    [fetch setPredicate:predicate];

    // sort it. Boring.
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetch setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"%d entities found.",[self.moContext countForFetchRequest:fetch error:&error]);
    // logs "3 entities found."; I added those properties before. See below for my saving "problem".
    if (error) NSLog("%@",error);
    // no error, thus nothing logged.

    [fetch setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *frController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetch managedObjectContext:self.moContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"cache"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = frController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [sort release];
    [frController release];
    [fetch release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Now it's getting weird. The above `NSLog` statement returns me the correct number of properties for the selected item. However, the UITableViewDelegate method tells me that there are no properties:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"Found %d properties for item \"%@\". Should have found %d.",[sectionInfo numberOfObjects], self.item.name, [self.item.properties count]);
    // logs "Found 0 properties for item "item". Should have found 3."
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

The same implementation works fine on the first level.

It's getting even weirder. I implemented some kind of UI to add properties. I create a new **Property** instance via `Property *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Property" inManagedObjectContext:self.moContext];`, set up the relationships and call `[self.moContext save:&error]`. This seems to work, as `error` is still `nil` and the object gets saved (I can see the number of properties when logging the **Item** instance, see above). However, the delegate methods are not fired. This seems to me due to the possibly messed up fetchRequest(Controller).

Any ideas? Did I mess up the second fetch request? Is this the right way to fetch all entities in a to-many-relationship for a particular instance at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually perform the fetch for the table view controller:

```
// ...create the fetch results controller...    
NSError *fetchRequestError;
BOOL success = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&fetchRequestError];
```

Comment: Way... too... simple. Thanks a lot, I should go get a coffee. :)

Comment: Well, it is a small bit of code stuck in the middle of a whole lot of other code. Core Data is a complicated beast.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, which line does the code snippet above replace?

Comment: These lines of code should be placed before [sort release], near the end.